# How to highlight bash/shell commands in markdown?

Tags: bash, shell, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

How can I highlight the Bash/shell commands in Markdown files?

---

For example, to highlight `js`, I write:

````
```js
function () { return "This code is highlighted as Javascript!"}
```
````

To highlight HTML code I use ```` ```html ````.

How can we highlight Bash/shell commands?

Comment: TL;DR: `\`\`\`shell` or `\`\`\`bash`

Answer (score 504, accepted):

It depends on the Markdown rendering engine and the Markdown flavour. There is no standard for this. If you mean GitHub flavoured Markdown for example, `shell` should work fine. Aliases are `sh`, `bash` or `zsh`. You can find the list of available syntax lexers [here](https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/master/lib/linguist/languages.yml).

Comment: I provided a bit more details on how to deduce language specifiers for Markdown from the linked file above here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45786100/6884590, in case that's useful to anyone finding this question.

Comment: Thanks. Also, `fish` is a valid language too. I didn't edit the answer because the question was around bash, but think it might be useful to others.

Answer (score 650):

If you are looking to highlight a shell session command sequence as it looks to the user (with prompts, not just as contents of a hypothetical script file), then the right identifier to use at the moment is **console**:

````
```console
foo@bar:~$ whoami
foo
```
````

[image: GitHub Markdown preview tab screenshot]

Comment: Nice! Is there a reference for this standard? Is it git flavored md or something else? Thanks!

Comment: @JorgeOrpinel I believe I dug it up in the list of languages supported by GitHub’s syntax highlighter [here](https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/master/lib/linguist/languages.yml#L4947).

Comment: https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/3c3b037910006fc2f1a9bb34b2c4e9cde062206c/lib/linguist/languages.yml#L5842-L5843 has listed both `console` and `bash session` as aliases for this `ShellSession` language, so my understanding is one could use `console`, `bash session` or `ShellSession` to achieve this but in reality only `console` and `shellsession` (case doesn't matter) worked for me in testing just now. `bash session` probably does work but I can't quote it right to include the space, so it just picks up `bash` in the beginning and drops `session`.

Comment: Do you know if the recommended identifier has changed? When I try `console` here at stackoverflow, I don't get any syntax highlighting. And `shell` and `bash` seem to think that everything is shell code, even command output (which are rows that don't include any `$`, I guess?).

Comment: @HelloGoodbye yes, it looks like it might not work as of today. I’m not sure if it’s intentional, since syntax highlighting on SO is [claimed](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) to work via highlight.js which apparently [does](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/blob/6b8c831f00c4e87ecd2189ebbd0bb3bbdde66c02/src/languages/shell.js#L13-L29) support `console` with prompts. I’m not feeling determined enough right now to see what version of highlight.js is used at SO and how it’s integrated… Could be a regression of some sort.

Comment: That said, just to keep it clear, the question posted originally is about GitHub-flavoured implementation of Markdown, which still relies on `linguist`, which still [supports](https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/249bbd1c2ffc631ca2ec628da26be5800eec3d48/lib/linguist/languages.yml#L6084-L6095) `console`. What’s used at SO seems like a different question.

Comment: (A question about StackOverflow itself may be best suited for the “meta” Q&A site.)

Answer (score 94):

I found a good description at *[Markdown Cheatsheet](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#code)*:

> **Code blocks are part of the Markdown spec, but syntax highlighting isn't**.
>
> However, many renderers -- like GitHub's and Markdown Here -- support syntax highlighting. Which languages are supported and how those language names should be written will vary from renderer to renderer. Markdown Here supports highlighting for dozens of languages (and not-really-languages, like diffs and HTTP headers); to see the complete list, and how to write the language names, see the [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/) demo page.

Although I could not find any official GitHub documentation about using `highlight.js`, I've tested lots of languages and seemed to be working

To see list of languages I used https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/blob/master/SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES.md

Some shell samples:

```
Shell:      console, shell
Bash:       bash, sh, zsh
PowerShell: powershell, ps
DOS:        dos, bat, cmd
```

Example:

````
```bat
cd \
copy a b
ping 192.168.0.1
```
````

Comment: I'm liking the `shell` one, thanks! It makes `$` seem dim.

Answer (score 51):

If I need only to highlight the first word as a command, I often use `properties`:

````
```properties
npm run build
```
````

I obtain something like:

**npm** run build

Comment: very useful for dotenv files

Answer (score 18):

Using the **knitr** package:

````
```{r, engine='bash', code_block_name} ...
````

E.g.:

````
```{r, engine='bash', count_lines}
wc -l en_US.twitter.txt
```
````

You can also use:

- `engine='sh'` for shell
- `engine='python'` for Python
- `engine='perl'`, `engine='haskell'` and a bunch of other C-like languages and even `gawk`, AWK, etc.

Comment: Does not do anything on a local .md file?  Does it have to be a web served doc to work?

Answer (score 18):

Per the [documentation from GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-and-highlighting-code-blocks/#syntax-highlighting) regarding GFM syntax highlighted code blocks

> We use [Linguist](https://github.com/github/linguist) to perform language detection and syntax highlighting. You can find out which keywords are valid in [the languages YAML file](https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/master/lib/linguist/languages.yml).

Rendered on GitHub, `console` makes the lines after the console blue. `bash`, `sh`, or `shell` don't seem to "highlight" much ...and you can use `posh` for PowerShell or CMD.

Answer (score 2):

Bitbucket uses CodeMirror for syntax highlighting. For Bash or shell you can use `sh`, `bash`, or `zsh`. More information can be found at *[Configuring syntax highlighting for file extensions](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/markdown-syntax-guide-776639995.html)* and *[Code mirror language modes](https://codemirror.net/mode/)*.

Answer (score 1):

In Obsidian, you can use `sh-session`

https://prismjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

````
```shell
your command line
```
````

OR

````
```bash
your command line
```
````