# In RStudio, can commands be sent from code chunks to the terminal?

Tags: r, rstudio

In RStudio, is it possible to have a code chunk that sends commands to the terminal (specifically Windows CMD prompt)? I know that I can use the command prompt via the "Terminal" tab in RStudio, but I would like to write these commands in a code chunk within a larger RMarkdown document. This way, when I click "Run All", the commands are sent automatically at the appropriate time.

Comment: The `system()`, `shell()`, or `system2()` commands (depending on your scenario) will all execute system commands from within R.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Highlight Bash/shell code in Markdown files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20303826/highlight-bash-shell-code-in-markdown-files)

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36928322/how-to-capture-the-output-of-system

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to capture the output of system()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36928322/how-to-capture-the-output-of-system)

Comment: Thanks, @danh, I was able to make it work using `shell()`